# Calling pointer of structs from nested functions

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a problem with calling structs, putting them as argument in a void function, and then call another void function, with argument taking the same struct, so I put them both pointers and the result is not showing up. If I call them separately, it works, but with the nested functions, it's not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct date {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
} date;

void next_day(date *d,int days)
{
        if(d->day < days) {
                int m = d->day + 1;
                d->day = m;
        }
        else
        {
                int m = d->year + 1;
                d->year = m;
                d->month = 1;
        }
}

void tom(date *d)
{
        switch(d->month)
        {
                case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 8: case 10: case 12:
                        next_day(&d,31);
                        break;
                case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11:
                        next_day(&d,30);
                        break;
                case 2:
                        if(d->year % 4 == 0)
                                next_day(&d,29);
                        else
                                next_day(&d,28);
                        break;
        }
}

int main(void)
{
        //date d = malloc(sizeof(date));
        date d;
        printf("Enter day, month, year: ");
        scanf("%d %d %d",&(d.day),&(d.month),&(d.year));
        tom(&d);
        printf("The next day is: %d %d %d",d.day,d.month,d.year);
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who would bother looking the code.

Comment: What do you mean by *the result is not showing up*?

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure your problem is with `next_day(&d,31);` You already have the address of the structure, you do not need to use the `&` operator again. Try calling it with `next_day(d,31);`.

This should have shown up in the compiler warning; always take care to read those warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
next_day(&d,31);   // At this point `d` is a pointer to a struct type.
```

You are sending the address of pointer, which means at the receiving end the function argument needs to be a pointer to a pointer ( i.e., `date **` ). But in your case, it is not.

```
void next_day(date *d,int days)
```

So, just do -

```
next_day(d,31);  // Notice the removal of &
```

Now `d` is of type `date *` and the receiving end also the argument is of type `date *`.